# Why my app works properly only in debug mode?

Tags: php

Without debugging when I submit form, $_POST array is still empty. During debugging in VSC everything works properly. I tried to run only html form without php code and POST data appeared.

My form:

```
<form action="/test" method="POST">
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"><br />
<label>Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="last_name"><br />
<label>Team:</label> <input type="text" name="team"><br />
<label>Contract expire:</label> <input type="text" name="contract_expire"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

My **index.php** file:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
require_once("src/Controller.php");
$config = require_once("config/config.php");
(new Controller($config))->action();
```

My **Controller.php** file:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

require_once("View.php");
require_once("Database.php");

class Controller
{
    private View $view;
    private Database $database;

    public function __construct(array $config){
        $this->view = new View();
        $this->database = new Database($config['db']);
    }

    public function action() {
        if($_POST){
            $params = [
                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                'team' => $_POST['team'],
                'contract_expire' => $_POST['contract_expire']
            ];

            $this->database->createDriver($params);
        }
        $this->view->render();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "not work" mean?  Please supply error messages or screenshots or a description of the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Based on what does requesting `/test` trigger the execution of your index.php?

Comment: _"I tried to run only html form without php code and POST data appeared."_ - appeared where?